# Case Statement does not execute

Tags: c++

This is a growing source of irritation for me at the moment, when I press the corresponding button for the cases (they're initialized above) they don't actually execute and I'm stuck in the menu.

I'm sure this is ridiculously simple and I'm just not seeing it.

Edit: Added more, upon request

```
const int POKER = 1;
const int EVAL = 2;
const int EXIT = 3;
const char FIVE_CARD = 'a';
const char TEXAS = 'b';
const char OMAHA = 'c';
const char SEVEN_CARD = 'd';
const char GO_BACK = 'e';
const char MENU[] = "\nPlease choose an option from the following:\n"
                    "1) Play Poker\n2) Set Evaluation Method\n3) Quit\n: ";
const char POKER_MENU[] = "\nPlease choose your game:\n"
                          "a) 5 Card Draw\nb) Texas Hold 'Em\nc) Omaha High\n"
                          "d) 7 Card Stud\ne) Go back\n: ";
int main()
{
int choice = 0;
char poker_choice;

do
{
    choice = askForInt(MENU, EXIT, POKER);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case POKER :
            do
            {
                choice = askForChar(POKER_MENU, GO_BACK, FIVE_CARD);
                switch(poker_choice)
                {
                    case FIVE_CARD :
                        std::cout << "Not implemented yet" << std::endl;
                        break;
                    case TEXAS :
                        std::cout << "Not implemented yet" << std::endl;
                        break;
                    case OMAHA :
                        std::cout << "Not implemented yet" << std::endl;
                        break;
                    case SEVEN_CARD :
                        std::cout << "Not implemented yet" << std::endl;
                        break;
                    case GO_BACK :
                        break;
                }
            }while(poker_choice != GO_BACK);
        case EVAL :
            std::cout << "Not implemented yet" << std::endl;
            break;
        case EXIT :
            break;
    }
}while(choice != EXIT);
```

Comment: You'll need to post the entire method...

Comment: Print the value of poker_choice before the switch statement, and the values of the cases. Also, make sure you are using an appropriate type.

Comment: Once inside the method, just print poker_choice and see if your the value is getting passes properly. Assuming all the cases FIVE_CARD, TEXAS are constants of the same data type.

Comment: Add a `default` label if you want to see that the program reaches that `switch`.

Comment: surely `choice = askForChar(POKER_MENU, GO_BACK, FIVE_CARD);` should be `poker_choice = askForChar(POKER_MENU, GO_BACK, FIVE_CARD);`?

Comment: -_- it most certainly is, I knew it was something I was simply overlooking. Make your comment an answer and I'll give it a big ol' green check mark. That fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`choice = askForChar(POKER_MENU, GO_BACK, FIVE_CARD);`
 should be
`poker_choice = askForChar(POKER_MENU, GO_BACK, FIVE_CARD);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned this is inside a method,

There are few things to check here;

> - Once inside the method, just print poker_choice and see if your the value is getting passed correctly.
> - Check if all the cases FIVE_CARD, TEXAS are declared as constants of the same data type.

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be on this line:

```
choice = askForChar(POKER_MENU, GO_BACK, FIVE_CARD);
```

You test `poker_choice` in your `switch` but you assign the value to `choice`.

It should be:

```
   poker_choice = askForChar(POKER_MENU, GO_BACK, FIVE_CARD);
// ^^^^^^

   switch(poker_choice)
   // ...
```